# Is it possible to play loading animation indicator while processing event in QT GUI application?

Tags: c++, qt

Below is my code, I have resolved to my Question .Al last i got solution with help of stack overflow team .It is possible to play animation (.gif file) on main thread if you are doing long task in worker thread.And other things is as with official doc QPixmap is does not supporting in worker thread .So i hope guys it will be help for Qt developer.

```
 int worker::do_Work()
 {
     int i =0;
     while (i<1000000)
     {
        qDebug()<<":count *i=========>"<<i;
        i++;
     }
    qDebug()<<"Worker process finished in Thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
    emit finished();
 }

int mywidget::popup()
{
   ui->label_2->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(85,255,127);border-radius:10px");
   ui->label_2->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   ui->label_2->setText("Please Wait..");
   ui->label_2->setAutoFillBackground(true);
   QMovie *movie = new QMovie(":images/loader.gif");
   ui->label_2->setMovie(movie);
   ui->label_2->show();
   qDebug()<<"labele show";
   movie->start();

   myWorker = new worker;
   WorkerThread = new QThread;
   myWorker->moveToThread(WorkerThread);

   connect(WorkerThread, SIGNAL(started()), myWorker, SLOT(do_Work()));
   WorkerThread->start();
   connect(myWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), ui->label_2, SLOT(close()));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is animation?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to populate loading.gif  animation  file on the screen  while web service call processing time .

Comment: You could show the animation code, since this depends on what is shown, it may be a blocking task.

Comment: We need to provide us with a code that is minimal and reproducible where the error is verified.

Comment: You could understand that we need a code that we can test and yours is not at all.

Comment: Why are you manually calling `processEvents()` twice and then deleting the label?

Comment: Actually my question is i want show loading indicator while another task is busy but i can't do if you knows please give your suggestion what should i do ?@ Jon Harper

Comment: @SubrataDas 
In SO you should not add SOLVED to the title of the question but mark the answer that helped you as correct, if none of the answers helped you and you have your own answer then I invite you to publish it and mark it as correct. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the [main loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exec) is busy because it is processing events, it will **not** update the GUI (because the GUI is managed by the main thread).

When you have long processing tasks, execute them in [a different thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html) (or accept to freeze your GUI).

---

As I said, the GUI is and **must be** managed in the main thread :

> GUI Thread and Worker Thread
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion.I have checked it's working but why QPixmap is not working in worker thread?-ymoreau

Comment: As it is said in the doc, you cannot perform GUI processing in the worker thread, it even uses `QPixmap` as an example which don't work in secondary threads.